# VBA excel AutoFilter usage

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I wonder how to use Excel VBA function AutoFilter to filter out rows with even number in it?

for example:

```
number 
1
2
4
3
6
5
```

How can I filter out rows with 2,4,6,8 (rows with an even number) in VBA by calling AutoFilter?

Comment: You can add an additional column equals 1 for even numbers,0 otherwise and then filter out by 1 or 0. If the data in A2, then in B2 type: `=IF(MOD(A2,2)=0,1,0)`

Comment: You need to have a helper column. In any column of the sheet referencing the "number" column, put a formula that return TRUE when even and sort by this helper column.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/929-excel-filter-even-odd-numbers.html#a1

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov Thanks, Could u show how can I do that helper column in VBA?

Comment: It's all explained in the link - step by step.

Comment: In addition to @braX comment - just use a macro recorder when adding this column manually.

Comment: @braX Thanks, that link helps, I just can not find how to do it in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using something like this:

```
Sub FilterEven()

    Dim rNumberColumn As Range

    ' Define the Column where you have the number For this example A1:A20.
    Set rNumberColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A21")

    ' Right Next to column A put the formulas and convert them to values.
    rNumberColumn.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=ISEVEN(A2)"
    rNumberColumn.Offset(, 1).Value = rNumberColumn.Offset(, 1).Value
    rNumberColumn.Offset(, 1).AutoFilter 1, "TRUE"
End Sub
```